# How to pass array to JqCloud?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have an issue regarding JqCloud, when I pass the php array to JqCloud it doesn't show the data.

```
<?php
    foreach($speakers as $key=>$val){
      $val->speaker_name;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var jArray= JSON.parse($speakers);

     $("#example").jQCloud([jArray], {
        width: 300,
        height: 200
     });
</script>

<div id="example" style="width: 550px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></div>
```

Please guide me how can I do this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

`var jArray= JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($speakers); ?>);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$speaker` is a PHP Array, the directly pass the variable `jArray` to `jQCloud()`

```
var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($speakers); ?>;
$("#example").jQCloud(jArray, {
   width: 300,
   height: 200    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can't use php variables in HTML

You have to use inside `<?php ?>`

```
 var array= <?php echo json_encode($speakers); ?>;
```

Then use it in your jQuery

```
$("#example").jQCloud(array, {
    width: 300,
    height: 200    
});
```